# array of pointers to strings

Tags: c, arrays

in a C Programming its given that we can't get the values using scanf() function to array of pointers but

```
int main()
{
char *names[6];
int loop;
scanf("%s",names[1]);
printftf("\n%s",names[1]);
}
```

it is working ,when i give the input as program ,i think it is storing the input,but it prints the output correctly as the given input.after that it gives a segmentation fault...
but when i do the same in a loop for getting 6 charecters

```
int main()
{
 char *names[6];
 int loop;
 for(loop=0;loop<6;loop++)
 scanf("%s",names[1]);
 for(loop=0;loop<6;loop++)
 printf("\n%s",names[1]);
 }
```

its not working please give me the answer...

Answer (score 11):

The issue is that you are not allocating any space for those *names*. You need to initialize each element in the array if you intend to use it with `scanf`.

```
char* names[6];
for( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    names[i] = malloc( 256 * sizeof *names[i] ); // or some other max value

scanf( "%s", names[1] );
```

Otherwise those *pointers* will be pointing anywhere in your memory, and attempting to read/write those locations will eventually result in a *segmentation fault*.

Comment: Nice answer, K-ballo.  Although the original code is a pretty trivial example, it is always recommended to check for NULL returns from malloc to trap out-of-memory conditions: if ((names[i] = malloc( 256 * sizeof(char)) == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Allocation error!\n"); exit(1)}.

Comment: Would `sizeof *names[0]` be better here than `sizeof(char)`?  That way it tracks the actual type, one less chance to overlook stuff.

Comment: Especially since `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: @jthill It's always encouraged to use `p = malloc(sizeof *p)` instead of `p = malloc(sizeof(T))`.

Comment: `*names` s/b `*names[i]`, you want the whole lhs expression not some intermediate pointer.

Answer (score 5):

In your code `names` is an array of 6 pointers to char. Now each of these pointers can store the starting point (the address of the first character) of a new string. This means you can store the starting addresses of 6 different strings in your `names` variable.

But when you use a loop to initialize each of these strings, you need to inform the machine HOW long each string might be, so that it can allocate a continuous block of addresses whose first address can then be stored in your pointer to **refer** to your string. Thus, you must **allocate** a certain size you think should be sufficient to store your string (eg: 256 bytes, 1 byte being 1 character). In the absence of this, the machine doesn't know where to store all the bytes of your string and throws a segmentation fault due to illegal memory access.

Thus to do this, **each of your 6 pointers** must be allocated some space to store a string. This will be done in your loop using `malloc()`. Based on @K-ballo's code:

```
char* names[6];
int max_length = 256; // The maximum length you expect
for( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    names[i] = malloc( max_length * sizeof(char) ); // allocates max_length number of bytes

scanf( "%s", names[1] );
```

So now you basically have a 6 different blocks of `max_length` continuous char addresses that are each referred to by `names[i]`. When you do the `scanf()` it reads the bytes from standard input and puts then into these allocated bytes in memory referred to by names[1].

I had a difficult time at the start understanding all this, so just thought an elaborate explanation would help. :)