# Create an array of strings without allocating each string

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to create an array of strings (considering I know the max length of each string).

```
char** strings = NULL;
strings = malloc (5*sizeof(char*));
```

Once I did that, how can I just fill the array without the need to allocate each string separately? Lets say I know the max length of a string is 20, how to I set it?

After the allocation of the string I wish to do the following:

```
strings[0] = "string";
strings[1] = "another string";
```

etc.

Thanks

Comment: `char (*strings)[20+1] = malloc(5*sizeof(*strings)); strcpy(strings[0], "string");...`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097651/array-of-pointers-to-strings

Comment: If you are assigning each (literal) string pointer manually, then you know how many there are, so dynamic allocation is not needed. You could achieve the same thing like this: `char *strings[5] = { "string", "another string", };`

Comment: thanks, but I don't know in advance what will be the string, I only know its max length. so I can't initialize it right away.

Comment: what is the source of your strings (constant, stream, file, string variable, ...)?

Comment: I'm reading it from a file

Comment: Your code `strings[0] = "string";` has to be done in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an array of pointers to `char` and then assign string literals to those pointers

```
char *strings[5]; 

strings[0] = "string";
strings[1] = "another string"; 
/* ... */
```

But note that, these strings will be immutable.

You can also use an array of `char` arrays

```
char strings[5][20];    // As you know max length of string is 20
strcpy(strings[0], "string");
strcpy(strings[1], "another string");
/* ... */
```

One of the advantage of latter is strings will be mutable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use it. One more question. Is it possible to use your code but to first initialize all strings to NULL?

Comment: `NULL` is used to initialize pointers, so initialising all pointers to `NULL` can be done in first snippet by `char *strings[5] = {NULL}`. This is not possible in second snippet as `strings[i]` is an array, not a pointer. Though, `char strings[5][20] = { {'\0'} };` will make all strings empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum size of each line, and if you know the maximum number of lines, you could simply define a two-dimensional array of chars, i.e. `char arr[5][20+1]`. Then you will have reserved space for up to 5 lines, each comprising up to 20 characters (+ null char).
And you could also define a type alias representing such a line (if you like):

```
#define MaxLineLength 20
typedef char Line[MaxLineLength+1];

int main() {

    Line input = { 0 };
    scanf("%20s", input);

    Line a[5] = { 0 };
    strcpy(a[0], input);
    strcpy(a[1], "string1");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I cannot follow the link from my environment; Can you describe the problem with the code?

Comment: 1) `typedef char Line[MaxLineLengh+1];` : _variably modified 'Line' at file scope_  It must be a constant in C.

Comment: 2) `Line input = {};` _ISO C forbids empty initializer braces_ This is GCC extension (or C++ ?).

Comment: I guess you are using C++ as C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Thanks for the comments. I'm using Apple LLVM with C99 [-std=C99], which accepted the code in my original post. But I usually have not set `-Wpedantic'. When doing so I get at least compiler warnings for the issues you posted. Again, thanks!

Comment: In my environment (1) is an error without `-pedantic` (ie `gcc -std=c99`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Hmm - not in mine: gcc -std=c99 main.c   ; clang/LLVM8.0. Will do some research; anyway, corrected the code...